# Incompatible types with T

Tags: java, generics

I have this method called *adapt* and I don't know exactly the difference between T and ?.

For me, *adapt* must be accept **any class**.

```
public void getRequestor(Long requestorId,  ResponseHandler<RequestorResponse> handler){
    String url = this.serviceUrl;

   //Error happens in this.adapt...
    RestClient.url(url).get(null).onResponse(this.adapt(handler), RequestorResponse.class); 
}

private <T> RestClient.ResponseHandler<T> adapt(ResponseHandler<T> handler){
    return new RestClient.ResponseHandler<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ResponseEntity<T> response) {
            if(response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                handler.onResponse(response.getBody());
                return;
            }
        handler.onError(new com.sensedia.api.interfaces.Error(String.valueOf(response.getStatusCodeValue())));
        }
    };
 }
```

RestClient class

```
public class RestClient {
   private final String url;

   private RestClient(String url) {
     this.url = url;
   }

   public static RestClient url(String url) {
      return new RestClient(url);
   }
    //Others methods 
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface ResponseHandler<T> {
       void onResponse(ResponseEntity<T> var1);
    }

    public static class PagedOperation<T> extends AbstractOperation<T, RestClient.PagedOperation<T>> {
        private final RestClient.Limit limit;
        private final RestClient.Offset offset;

        public PagedOperation(String url, RestClient.Limit limit, RestClient.Offset offset) {
            super(url);
            this.limit = limit;
            this.offset = offset;
        }

        public void onResponse(RestClient.ResponseHandler<T> handler, Class<T> type) {
            UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(this.url()).queryParam("_limit", new Object[]{this.limit.get()}).queryParam("_offset", new Object[]{this.offset.get()});
            ResponseEntity<T> response = this.client().getForEntity(builder.build().encode().toUri(), type);
            handler.onResponse(response);
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't pass this *handler*. Why this happens?

Error

> incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to equality
>   constraint(s) [ERROR] inferred: java.lang.Object [ERROR] equality
>   constraints(s): java.lang.Object,com.daniela.infra.RequestorResponse

Comment: What does `this` refer to?

Comment: What is the definition of the `onResponse` method you are calling there? It's not the one you've shown higher up, this one has two parameters.

Comment: RestClient is a class which uses Spring's RestTemplate and it's easy make API paginations with it.

Comment: How does `RestClient.url(url).get(null)` become a `RestClient<RequestorResponse>`? I'd guess you have to hint somehow, e.g. casting the null: `....get((RequestorResponse) null)`.

Comment: Please show the definitions of the `RestClient.url` and `(whatever that type is).get` methods.

Comment: Please refine your code example. Looks like you posted code which isn't used and didn't post code which is used. Impossible to tell what's wrong exactly at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are trying to pass defined Class `RequestorResponse` into a generic type `this.adapt(handler)`

> ResponseHandler < RequestorResponse > handler

Java won't allow you to that because your Generic Type `T` may be different class than `RequestorResponse`

I suggest you to do this

```
public void getRequestor(Long requestorId,  ResponseHandler<T> handler){
    String url = this.serviceUrl;
    RestClient.url(url).get(null).onResponse(this.adapt(handler), RequestorResponse.class);
}
```

Or change this.adapt to

```
private <T> RestClient.ResponseHandler<T> adapt(ResponseHandler<?> handler){
```

Here some references :

1. `<T>` Generic Type : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html
2. `<?>` Wildcard : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html